# Problem with simple tcp\ip client-server

Tags: c#, .net, networking, tcp, ip

i'm trying to write simple tcp\ip client-server.

here is server code:

```
 internal class Program
    {
        private const int _localPort = 7777;

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpListener Listener;
            Socket ClientSock; 
            string data;
            byte[] cldata = new byte[1024]; 

            Listener = new TcpListener(_localPort);
            Listener.Start(); 
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting connections [" + Convert.ToString(_localPort) + "]...");
            try
            {
                ClientSock = Listener.AcceptSocket(); 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return;
            }
            int i = 0;

            if (ClientSock.Connected)
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        i = ClientSock.Receive(cldata); 
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        if (i > 0)
                        {

                            data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(cldata).Trim();

                            ClientSock.Send(cldata);
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        ClientSock.Close(); 
                        Listener.Stop();
                        Console.WriteLine(
                            "Server closing. Reason: client offline. Type EXIT to quit the application.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is client code:

```
void Main()
{
         string data; // Юзерская дата
            byte[] remdata ={ };
            TcpClient Client = new TcpClient();

            string ip = "127.0.0.1";
            int port = 7777;

            Console.WriteLine("\r\nConnecting to server...");
            try
            {
                Client.Connect(ip, port);
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot connect to remote host!");
                return;
            }
            Console.Write("done\r\nTo end, type 'END'");
            Socket Sock = Client.Client; 

            while (true) 
            {
                Console.Write("\r\n>");
                data = Console.ReadLine();
                if (data == "END")
                    break;
                Sock.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data)); 
                Sock.Receive(remdata);
                Console.Write("\r\n<" + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(remdata));
            }

            Sock.Close();
            Client.Close();
}
```

When i'm sending to my server i cannt receive data back answer. Sock.Receive(remdata) returns nothing! Why?

Comment: You wont be able to get any exception if you try to hide or mask the exceptions generated. In catch, throw the exceptions. Dont mask. Then youll know wheres the problem is.
Or are you seeing any console messages being printed? Please provide more debug info

Comment: Exception masked in only place. But it works ok. Problem on client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to receive to an empty buffer. You should allocate the buffer with a sensible size, and then take note of the amount of data received:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

...

int bytesReceived = socket.Receive(buffer);
string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesReceived);
```

(It's somewhat unconventional to use PascalCase for local variables, by the way. I'd also urge you *not* to just catch Exception blindly, and not to swallow exceptions without logging them.)

Comment: Thanks. it's great how you can see where is problem so fast!